# How can I create an event with addEvent with select: scroll?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I wanted to ask this question I had while messing about with fullcalendar. What I'm trying to achieve here is that a user has a calendar and has an option to select which dates they want by dragging their mouse and selecting. We can do this with `selectable: true`, but that's not the issue. The issue is I'm having trouble adding the event after the dates have been triggered.

The issue I think I'm having is that I can't properly define the start and end points. The code I saw in examples had components where you manually wrote the date but this is determined by scroll. So can anyone help?

This is my code.

```
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    themeSystem: 'Lumen',
    selectable: 'true',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    select: function(start, end) {
      var title = prompt("Event Content:");
      var eventData;
      if (title) {
        eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end
        };
        
      }
      if(eventData) {
        calendar.addEvent({
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end,
          allDay: true
        });
      }

    },
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

I'll explain what's going on here. The select function asks for a prompt when you select dates, which works! But the if statements what I'm trying to do is write down the data in an array with eventData. But when I have calendar.addEvent, I'm struggling determining the start and end points. Instead of the bars popping up to signify an event, it does nothing.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance, lemme know if you need more info.

Comment: `select: function(start, end) {` is incorrect. Review the documentation again carefully: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback

Comment: Is it not? I'm inspecting this example https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001 and they use `dateClick` and `select: function(info)`; the documentation also says inside the info you can have selectionInfo. Sorry for bugging ya, but what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! (To anyone who is viewing this in the future, what I did was replace all of the select function with ```select: function(info) {
      var title= prompt('Event Content:')
      calendar.addEvent({
        title: title,
        start: info.startStr, 
        end: info.endStr,
        allDay: true
      })
    }```

Comment: Yep, `function(info)` isn't the same as `function(start, end)` :-). Glad you figured it out.